# How to compare strings in javascript ignoring special characters

Tags: javascript, unicode, string-comparison

I'm developing an app and I've been asked to compare strings, but text in string have special characters (spanish accents like "á", "é", "í", "ó" and "ú")

I already manage capitalization with `toUpperCase()`, but still, I want to be sure that I have no problem with accents.

What I have to do is to compare some words already saved in system and check if used typed any of them.

What I do is store the typed words in an array, and then proceed to analyze them in another function (yet to be implemented)

This is my function where I store the words the user types (it may change to make it more complete):

```
function clickNewWord(){
    var theWord = textField.value.toUpperCase();
    ArrayWrittenWords.push(theWord);
    textField.value = "";
}
```

PD: I'll take the opportunity to ask: What would be the correct coding to work with accents? UTF-8?

Comment: When you say you want to "ignore" the accents, what do you mean? Do you mean that `ole` would match `òle`?

Comment: yes! that's what I want :)

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700636/using-javascript-to-perform-text-matches-with-without-accented-characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert them and then match them, let me if my example is clear :)

```
var stringInTheSystem = ['aaaa','bbbb'];// Array of string in your system;

var term = 'áaaa';// the word you want to compare it; 
term = term.replace(/á/g, "a"); 
term = term.replace(/é/g, "e"); 
term = term.replace(/í/g, "i"); 
term = term.replace(/ó/g, "o"); 
term = term.replace(/ú/g, "u"); 
var matcher = new RegExp( term, "i" );
$.grep( stringInTheSystem, function( value ) {
                  value = value.test || value.value || value;
                    console.log(matcher.test( value ));
});
```

Comment: Yes you shoud UpperCase all strings and then use this code

Comment: Hey, while this code works fine when text with accents is in code, but when I have to read it from textarea with "textField.value.toUpperCase();" it doesn't work. Why is this happennig?

Comment: Please, as I told you in my last comment, I found other issue and I'd like to solve it without asking a new question (as you can see I only work in this project on fridays)

Answer (score 10):

Although its an old question however, for the sake of future googlers here is the [best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/10284252) way to remove accent from a string:

```
var string = 'á é í ó ú';
string.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
>a e i o u
```