# Spring-boot + mongodb does not find word with accent

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, accent-insensitive

Good morning people,

I'm having trouble using MongoRepository with spring-boot,
I created my query interfaces to access mongodb collections, and the following situation is happening.

Ex: I have a Document with "title" attribute and its value "Christmas Promotion", I created a method to search for the title ie findByTitleLikeIgnoreCase (String title), but when I search for "promoção" without the accents does not return the record, if I typing with accent usually brings.

Doing the direct query in the bank or using mongodriver works, I have also tested it with TextCriteria and it works, but using the MongoRepository interface I have this problem, has anyone else gone through this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647244/mongodb-how-to-find-documents-ignoring-case-sensitive-accents-and-percent-like

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707671/mongodb-match-accented-characters-as-underlying-character