# Performing a diacritics-insensitive $regex search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

as the title says, I am trying to figure out how to perform a diacritics-insensitive `$regex` search in MongoDB, although at this point I am not sure if that's even possible.

Basically, imagine we have a **Teams** collection with a documents like these:

```json
{ id: 1, name: "FC Bayern München" },
{ id: 2, name: "Atlético Madrid" }
```

For this collection, I have created a `text` index for the `name` field:

`db.getCollection('teams').createIndex({name: 'text'});`

This allows me to perform a diacritics and case-insensitive search.

```js
db.getCollection('teams').find({ $text: { $search: "bayern" }});
db.getCollection('teams').find({ $text: { $search: "munchen" }});
// ✅ { id: 1, name: "FC Bayern München" }
```

However, if the text search doesn't include a full word (`Bayern`, `Munchen`), the query produces no results:

```js
db.getCollection('teams').find({ $text: { $search: "bayer" }});
db.getCollection('teams').find({ $text: { $search: "munc" }});
// ❌ (no results)
```

So to make this work as intended, I need to use `$regex` search instead, however, I can't seem to find a way to ignore diacritics.

```js
db.getCollection('teams').find({ name: { $regex: "baye", $options: 'i' }});
// ✅ { id: 1, name: "FC Bayern München" }

db.getCollection('teams').find({ name: { $regex: "munchen", $options: 'i' }});
// ❌ (no results)
```

So my question is, is there any way to achieve this universal search that can search both diacritics-insensitively and not having to match whole words, via regular expression or other means?

Comment: @turivishal I know, that's the entire point. I want to be able to perform a search that would match both `u` and `ü` universally (diacritics).

Comment: Any solutions on this?

Comment: @AlexTotolici I haven't really looked much into it since, but I have been loosely following MongoDB updates and I haven't heard or read anything about it.

Comment: there is a workaround in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647244/mongodb-how-to-find-documents-ignoring-case-sensitive-accents-and-percent-like 
because mongoo regex dont support u option https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Answer (score 1):

If you use MongoDB Atlas, you can [create an autocomplete index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/field-types/autocomplete-type/) on your `name` field with `edgeGram` tokenization and `foldDiacritics` set to `true`:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "type": "autocomplete",
        "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
        "tokenization": "edgeGram",
        "minGrams": 1,
        "maxGrams": 5,
        "foldDiacritics": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will let you issue `$search` queries with the behavior you're seeking (prefix matching of words, ignoring diacritics).